# Why the new version of EGIT(3.3.x) has errors on my system and eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

1.
I'm still using windows xp SP3(x86),because My computer can't  install Vista&win7&win8 etc. So do not ask me to update win7 or greater . :)

2.
It's going well when I'm using :(1)Eclipse jee Juno SR2 + EGIT3.2 (2) Eclipse jee kepler SR2 + EGIT3.2.

3.
When I updated Egit to the latest  version:now is 3.3.2, an error occurred during some operat about git and github.It shows: **An internal error occurred during: "Computing Git status for repository xxx".Symbolic links not supported on this operating system.**

Why it's happening ?And what should I do?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse EGit bug [429947](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429947) targeted to be fixed in EGit 3.4. The EGit 3.3 symbolic link code is failing to deal with the fact that Windows XP does not support symbolic links.

You should stay with EGit 3.2

Comment: yeah thanks,I got it. I will choose 3 ways:(1)stay with EGit 3.2 (2) Use EGIT Nightly Builds (3)Use eclipse for code only,use Git Bash for commit and push.

Comment: You could also just uninstall "Java implementation of Git - optional Java 7 libraries", it's not needed in your case.